# pyarrow and pandas integration

Tags: pandas, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I plan to:

- join
- group by
- filter

data using pyarrow (new to it). The idea is to get better performance and memory utilisation ( apache arrow compression) comparing to pandas.

Seems like pyarrow has no support for join two Tables / Dataset by key so I have to fallback to pandas.

I don't really follow how pyarrow <-> pandas integration works. Will pandas realy on apache arrow data structure? I'm fine with using only these types.

- string
- long
- decimal

I have a feeling that pandas will copy all data from apache arrow and double size (according to the doc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pyarrow` itself doesn't provide these capabilities to the end user but is rather meant as a library that can be used by DataFrame library developers as the base. Thus the intention is not that you as a DataFrame user switch one day to using `pyarrow` directly but that libraries like `pandas` use Arrow as a backend.

This is already happening with the new ArrowStringType introduced in `pandas` 1.2 (not yet really functional) or the [`fletcher`](https://github.com/xhochy/fletcher) library that provides the possibility to use `pyarrow` as the backend for a selection of the columns of your `pandas.DataFrame` through `pandas`'s `ExtensionArray` interface.

Disclaimer: I'm the main author of `fletcher`.