# Having trouble to import the library pandas

Tags: python, pandas, import, pyarrow

Pyarrow will become a required dependency of pandas in the next major release of pandas (pandas 3.0)

-everytime I execute on PyCharm "import pandas as pd" I got this error

Give me solution what should I install or upgrade.

Answer (score 13):

I just run `pip install Pyarrow` and then it worked.  The warning clearly specified that the Pyarrow will be a major component in the next release.

> Pyarrow will become a required dependency of pandas in the next major release of pandas (pandas 3.0),

Answer (score 1):

DeprecationWarning:
Pyarrow will become a required dependency of pandas in the next major release of pandas (pandas 3.0),
(to allow more performant data types, such as the Arrow string type, and better interoperability with other libraries)
but was not found to be installed on your system.
If this would cause problems for you,
please provide us feedback at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54466

I believe this to be a warning message as the title states: 'DeprecationWarning'

Basic test example:

```
import pandas as pd

# create pandas data set function name() using pandas
def name():
    name = 'Jack'
    surname = 'Crowley'
    name_dataset = {
        'Name': [name],
        'Surname': [surname],

        }


    name_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(name_dataset, )

    return name_dataframe

# call and print the name function
print(name())
```

The above basic code outputs as below:

import pandas
Name  Surname
0  Jack  Crowley

NB: for more info on this visit [pyarrow and pandas integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65531865/pyarrow-and-pandas-integration)

or just:

pip install pyarrow

Answer (score 0):

If you're running with a virtual environment (venv). You can use the below command to install Pyarrow and get rid of the warning.

```bash
pipx install --include-deps Pyarrow
```